# How to update submodule to a specific commit from a repo without branch name?

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket, git-submodules

While working with git submodules I had a though to update the submodule
by providing only the submodule repository URL and commit id ( Commit id could be present in any branch of the submodule repository. )

So i tried to update that but i failed to do with out branch name mentioned.

**Now i am cloning the repo and with `git reset --hard <commit_id>` doing**.

please give me some idea or if anything there about, how can I update the git submodule
with only submodule repo URL and a commit id from any branch of the submodule repo URL?

Answer (score 0):

Root repositories refer submodules via commit sha1, thus submodules are checked out as detached from branches.

You can just checkout to the required commit of the submodule (after fetching origin of course):

```
git checkout <commit_id>
```

Comment: 1. I will pull the latest changes from the sub module repo
2. Then i will checkout to the commit 
3. Then i will push it to the main repo 

is that correct what i understood ?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. 3 is rather commit and push.